# How can a parameter value from a URL be inserted as a variable in a Google Analytics code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the following url:

```
domain.com/product/page.html?user_is=234
```

And using JavaScript, I am picking up the variable value in the 'user' parameter:

```
  var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  var user_value = urlParams.get('user_is');
```

And GA code that looks like this in the target button I am looking to target:

```
<button class="code" onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {eventCategory: 'Yes Code',eventAction: 'click',eventLabel: 'user_value'});">
```

What I am struggling with is getting the value in 'user_value' to be rendered in the GA code so I can track a specific user's click. It appears I cannot render this variable using JavaScript. What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `gtag` function inline you can create a helper function to get value and assign it to `user_value` and then call `gtag`

```
<button class="code" onclick="handleGtag()">
```

Function

```
function handleGtag(){
 var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
 var user_value = urlParams.get('user_is');
 gtag('event', 'click', {eventCategory: 'Yes Code',eventAction: 'click',eventLabel: user_value});
}
```